# Why is model invalid when i try to save text from TinyMCE

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, umbraco8

I am using TinyMCE and when i try to save text from textarea i get the message that value is not valid.

I have tried with encoding and without it and result is the same.

Model:

```
   [UIHint("tinymce_jquery_full"), AllowHtml]
    public IHtmlString Text { get; set; }
```

TinyMCE:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea.rte',
    height: 400,
    menubar: false,
    branding: false,
    plugins: [
        "paste",
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
        "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
    ],
    encoding: 'xml',
    paste_as_text: true,
    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link"
});
```

Comment: It's been awhile since I use tinyMCE but I think you have to save the content to the textarea first.  https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#save

Comment: What is the value of `Text` set to specifically?

Comment: If i type "some text" in "text" field , the value is this: &lt;p&gt;some text&lt;/p&gt;
If i understund your question.

Comment: Ok, now i understund what is wrong with this. I changed IHtmlstring to string and now its working, problem was that IHtmlstring  should not be encoded twice.